# Importing a PHP page into Oracle APEX?

Tags: html, database, oracle, oracle-apex

Can this be done and if so how? ~TIA

Comment: By "import" do you mean to run the PHP code inside APEX (PL/SQL)? Or do you just need to get the results of running a PHP page?

Answer (score 1):

Oracle APEX does not use anything even closely related to PHP to build HTML. What you're probably going to do is build a page based off the same SQL as is used in the PHP page.